# Java REST API URL passed in AngularJS not working

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, rest, http

I am new to AngularJS, i am trying to get the data using REST api url and i am trying to pass the URL to angularjs and display the data in HTML. But it shows Internal Server Error. Please find the screenshot of error and rest URL data

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is my HTML,

```
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">
  </script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/WebApplication1/webresources/rest.employee/Show/1"
      }).then(function mySucces(response) {
        $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
      }, function myError(response) {
        $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  {{myWelcome}}
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what error you are seeing in console of debugger/developer tool in browser ?

Comment: I have included another screenshot of console error...

Comment: Then you should check at the server side what's going on there

Comment: It's hard to determine what exactly is going on with only the information you have provided. I am inclined to believe that this error is happening server-side. Yes, you are pinging the server with a request but if you are hitting your target endpoint with the proper payload and your server is giving you back a 500 then your server isn't configured properly or your server is expecting an explicit payload that you aren't providing. Please debug your server side code and reply with what you are observing.

Answer (score 1):

This may be because the response content-type is xml. Try [angular-xml](https://github.com/johngeorgewright/angular-xml) or this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Korilakkuma/92a8f1ec3e87600a0293)

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWcxa.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCelZ.jpg)

***Step 1***: Right Click on chrome icon then Select **Property** Menu

***Step 2***: Select **Shortcut** Tab. then below in  **Target** text box already some path will be there. 
*example: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"*

Don't change the path add  **--user-data-dir="C:/Chrome" --disable-web-security**  this text at the end of the path.

Example: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome" --disable-web-security

***Step3***: Then Click **Ok Button**